# Why some GNU parallel input include quotes?

Tags: unix, awk, parallel-processing, gnu

Gnu parallel input (e.g. from a pipe) automatically single quotes input that contains space or symbols like / and : 
Is there a reason for that? How can I print the input as it is without any quote?

I tried with various parallel options like -q or with different type of quotes to embed the input in the parallel command, however, it always shows up with single quotes when the input contains space of / symbols.

Here are the command lines I tried:

```
awk '{print "ftp://"$1}' assembly2contig.lst | parallel --dry-run wget '{}'
```

Output will be

```
wget 'ftp://mypath'
```

```
awk '{print $1}' assembly2contig.lst | parallel --dry-run wget 'ftp://{}'
```

This command works but I need to build my path within parallel which is not very convenient for my cases, e.g. when my input file already contains paths.

I would like to obtain

```
wget ftp://mypath
```

using ftp://mypath as parallel input coming from the pipe (e.g. awk)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the quoting is to avoid the default behaviour in xargs:

```
echo 'two  spaces  lost' | xargs echo
echo 'two  spaces  kept' | parallel echo
```

To avoid this you can use `eval`:

```
echo 'two  spaces  lost' | parallel eval echo
```

Comment: I ended up with something like this `echo 'mypath' | parallel 'wget $(eval echo ftp://{})'`

Answer (score 0):

If `assembly2contig.lst` looks like this:

```
hp.com/something abcde 1234
ibm.com/other fred 3390
bbc.co.uk/film1 bill 999
```

You could avoid `awk` altogether and use:

```
parallel --colsep ' ' --dry-run -a assembly2contig.lst wget ftp://{1}
```

Or if the input is a pipe:

```
cat assembly2contig.lst | parallel --colsep ' ' --dry-run wget ftp://{1}
```

**Sample Output**

```
wget ftp://hp.com/something
wget ftp://ibm.com/other
wget ftp://bbc.co.uk/film1
```

Comment: I need to get the input from a pipe (I simplified the line with a simple awk command), so -a is not an option in my situation. Is there a way to remove the simple quote on parallel input or does the only way is to preprocess the whole command line I wish to execute prior calling parallel?